# Group two object attributes in a list

Tags: java, java-stream

I would like to transform a duplicate object with different values to a list in java, as follows

```
[
  {
    "code": "code",
    "active": true,
    "car": "Sedan"
  },
  {
    "code": "code",
    "active": true,
    "car": "R4"
  },
  {
    "code": "code2",
    "active": false,
    "car": "Sedan"
  },
  {
    "code": "code2",
    "active": false,
    "car": "R4"
  }
]
```

**ClassOne**

```
public class Car{

    private String code;
    private boolean active;
    private String car;

}
```

if "code" and "active" are the same, I would like to group them in a single object

```
[
  {
    "code": "code",
    "active": true,
    "name": {
      "cars": [
        {
          "brand": "Sedan"
        },
        {
          "brand": "R4"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "code": "code2",
    "active": false,
    "name": {
      "cars": [
        {
          "brand": "Sedan"
        },
        {
          "brand": "R4"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

**Class parse**

```
public class CarParse{

    private String code;
    private String active;
    private Name name;

}
```

```
public class Name{

    private List<Brand> cars;

}
```

```
public class Brand{

    private String brand;

}
```

Then it would be to go from ClassOne to ClassParse,transforming the objects grouped by "code" and "active

Comment: You are showing json but you code is not showing any json code. What json package are you using? BTW; You know that active is a boolean in the json but not in you java code.

Comment: You dont need a Name object, Just use `Map<String, List<Brand>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find writing the non [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) easier first.

For example, group the input objects on `code-active` will form a unique pair that you can loop over, then build the final list from

```
public List<CarParse> getParsed(List<Car> cars) {
    Map<String, CarParse> codeMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (Car c : cars) {
      CarParse cp;
      List<Brand> brands;
      String code = c.getCode();
      boolean active = c.isActive();
      String group = String.format("%s-%s", code, active);
      Brand b = new Brand(c.getCar());
      if (codeMap.containsKey(group)) {
        cp = codeMap.get(group);
        brands = cp.getName().getCars();
        brands.add(b);
      } else {
        brands = new ArrayList<>();
        brands.add(b);
        Name n = new Name(brands);
        cp = new CarParse(code, active, n);
        codeMap.put(group, cp);
      }
    }

    return new ArrayList<>(codeMap.values());
}
```

Stream version

```
return new ArrayList<>(cars.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
    c -> String.format("%s-%s", c.getCode(), c.isActive()),
    c -> {
      ArrayList<Brand> brands = new ArrayList<>();
      brands.add(new Brand(c.getCar()));
      return new CarParse(c.getCode(), c.isActive(), new Name(brands));
    },
    (v1, v2) -> {
      if (v1.isActive() == v2.isActive() && (v1.getCode().equals(v2.getCode()))) {
        for (Brand b : v2.getName().getCars()) {
          v1.getName().getCars().add(b);
        }
        return v1;
      }
      return v1;
    })).values());
```

Output

```json
[ {
  "code" : "code",
  "active" : true,
  "name" : {
    "cars" : [ {
      "brand" : "Sedan"
    }, {
      "brand" : "R4"
    } ]
  }
}, {
  "code" : "code2",
  "active" : false,
  "name" : {
    "cars" : [ {
      "brand" : "Sedan"
    }, {
      "brand" : "R4"
    } ]
  }
} ]
```